# Template to include Title, CreateDate, ModifiedBy, Author etc in C# Class file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Is there any template available which inserts xml comments on the class file(before/after using statements) to include ClassName, Author, File CreateDate, ModifiedBy, BugFixes etc. So any developer adding a new class file should be able to provide these information before writing the code.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that what source control is for.  I have always found a list of bug fixes at the top of a file very confusing and hard to follow - especially since you only see the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom **code snippet** and have everyone on the team use that.

Grz, Kris.

Comment: Thanks. Can we modify the T4 template for the c# class file? So developers don't forget.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to customize the template: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247119(v=VS.80).aspx.